# Automation for testing desktop application with chromium,WPF,awesomium

Tags: wpf, automation, chromium-embedded, awesomium

We have a desktop application developed with below technologies

WPF,
Chromium,
awesomium controls

Can anyone suggest me any tool for automating this application
We tried all popular tools in market but no luck.

Let me know if anyone have worked on these application or please provide any suggestions

Comment: Which tools did you try for now? Have you looked at open source tools like TestStack.White or Winium.Desktop?

Comment: We tried tools like UFT,Ranorex,TestComplete...But no use   . We are looking for tool which not only support desktop application but also it should identify awesomium controls

Comment: I thought of giving TestStack.White a try. I installed "Visual UI Automation Verify" tool and tried identifying the objects.  The tool is able to identify wpf controls, but unable to identify awesomium controls on chromium.

Comment: Didn't hear about awesomium before. Probably these controls don't implement UIA providers to support Microsoft UI Automation technology. Or they require some special steps to enable accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar application to test. I used UIA for WinForm and WPF.

After a lot of research, For Chromium interface, since it's not UIA implementation and browser embedded UI and since the code for web browser and desktop is same. I preferred testing that module in web browser than desktop.

The only other way I found is by using Sikuli. Since it is based on images, I couldn't rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ranorex studio, there inside plugin sections you can configure CEF settings as well as WPF settings.
More info - https://www.ranorex.com/